# Is it possible to connect a NAS to both WAN and LAN at the same time?

Tags: networking, lan, nas, network-adapter, wan

Thinking of upgrading my Synology DS209 NAS to a newer model with dual gigabit ethernet connections. Currently my NAS sits outside my LAN, connected to WAN through one of my modem's four ports, getting it's own outside static IP. New, full website updates in this configuration, however, are extremely slow at about 15 minutes, compared to 4 minutes if I plug the NAS directly into my gigabit router (influenced by upload/download speed, the NAT and travel time to my local ISP and back.)

My question: Is it possible to connect a NAS to both WAN and LAN at the same time? The new unit I'm looking at has dual gigabit connections, and while I'm aware they may be limitations on the hardware/software for the new unit, this is more of a general 'Can it/Has it been done?' enquiry, if you've heard/seen this setup previously. I would like to host my website and fast upload, being connected to both my LAN and the web at the same time.

Comment: I would assume connecting to more than one network is the purpose of having dual Ethernet connections.

Comment: Hmmm, well, I know that people often connect two ISP/WANs for a dual ethernet device, but didn't know if that was behind/in front of a router, or if they could be mix n match. I suppose the adapters would be independently configurable? I'll be using the same ISP connection for both ports, with one port obtaining a static IP directly from the modem, the other one assigned a static IP in my router's DHCP... connected to the same modem. I'm hoping to hear from someone who's done this kind of setup before. Crossing my fingers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. Normal for servers to be connected to different network segments. Doesn't matter wan or lan.

Comment: Thanks! I came to understand that the NAS would figure out which network was connected to either port and route the traffic accordingly. Nice.